# random numbers for array keys, and the same random number for duplicates

Tags: php

I'm trying to split tasks for two persons randomly by generating random number for every task from 1 to 2.

the problem is that I have duplicate tasks.
how to generate the same number for duplicates without having to delete them  ?
example :

```
<?php 
$tasks = array('task1','task4','task2','task3','task4','task3','task4','task5'); 


foreach($tasks as $task)
{
    $rand = rand(1,2);
    $array = array('task' => $task,'rand'=> $rand);
    echo $array['task']."==>";
    echo $array['rand']."<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want as output?

Answer (score 2):

#### The easy way: Use array keys

```
$tasks = array('task1', 'task4', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4', 'task3', 'task4', 'task5');

$output = [];

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    if (!isset($output[$task])) {
        $output[$task] = rand(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Result: `var_dump($output);`

```
array (size=5)
  'task1' => int 2
  'task4' => int 2
  'task2' => int 2
  'task3' => int 1
  'task5' => int 1
```

Get the number for a certain task:
`var_dump($output['task3']);`

```
int 1
```

This is easy to use, but the duplicates will be deleted. As you said, you don't like that. (But it would be easier)

#### Without deleting and keeping the original array sorting

There you need a new array, with task and the number.

```
$tasks = array('task1', 'task4', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4', 'task3', 'task4', 'task5');

$numbers = []; // saving the random number, so the same task will get the same number
$result = [];

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    if (isset($result[$task])) {
        $number = $numbers[$task];
    } else {
        $number = rand(1, 2);
        $numbers[$task] = $number;
    }

    $result[] = [
        'task' => $task,
        'number' => $number,
    ];

    // or $result[] = $number;
    // then only the number is saved at the position of $task
}
```

result `var_dump($result);`

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'task' => string 'task1' (length=5)
      'number' => int 2
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'task' => string 'task4' (length=5)
      'number' => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'task' => string 'task2' (length=5)
      'number' => int 2
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'task' => string 'task3' (length=5)
      'number' => int 2
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'task' => string 'task4' (length=5)
      'number' => int 1
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'task' => string 'task3' (length=5)
      'number' => int 2
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'task' => string 'task4' (length=5)
      'number' => int 1
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'task' => string 'task5' (length=5)
      'number' => int 1
```

Comment: In your second piece of code, you have an array `$result` which is never added to in a way that `$result[$task]` makes any sense.

Comment: Look at `$result[] = ['task' => $task,'number' => $number,];` There, the current entry is added to `$result`

Comment: Sorry - I had hit enter before completing my comment.

Comment: Ah, OK. But if you use an array key a second time you, would just change the entry you already have. You wouldn't add anything. This means, the duplicates would be deleted. See solution 1. There it happens that way.

Comment: But currently, this code may return different numbers for the same task - as it can never match a task against the previous one chosen.

Comment: You could add only the number: `$result[] = $number;` Then you can access the task name with `$task[$x]` and the number with `$result[$x]`. If you want an array, where you can access the number via name, you need solution 1.

Comment: Using `$result[]` will result in an array with keys 0, 1... `$result[$task]` is looking for something like `$result['task4']` - which will never exist.

Comment: Take solution 1

Comment: Or alternatively `if (isset($numbers[$task])) {` which is what I assumed the `$numbers` array was for.

Answer (score 0):

You could us `array_fill_keys()` to create an array with all the tasks as keys, then use `array_walk()` to assign random numbers to all the keys.

```
$tasks = array('task1','task4','task2','task3','task4','task3','task4','task5'); 

//use the tasks as keys for a new array. Duplicates will be filtered out.
$task_rand = array_fill_keys( $tasks, false );

//then "walk" the new array, assigning a randum number to each task
array_walk($task_rand, function(&$value){$value= rand(1,2);});

//sort the array, so task1 comes before task2 etc
ksort($task_rand);

The result of `$task_rand`:
Array
(
[task1] => 2
[task2] => 1
[task3] => 2
[task4] => 1
[task5] => 1
)
```